# Confused about a function in Learn Python the Hard Way ex41?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, function

I got stuck on another part of this exercise. The program that is being coded allows you to drill phrases (It gives you a piece of code, you write out the English translation) and I'm confused on how the "convert" function works. Full code: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html

```
def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results
```

I'm pretty lost. Is "w" from `w.capitalize()` a file itself, or is it just referring to the objects in the list? I'm also not sure why the `.count()` function is in the argument for `.sample()` (or what `.sample()` really does). What is the purpose of the first for_loop?

Thank you for any and all help - I'm sorry for the barrage of questions.

Comment: When you're not sure what a function from the standard library does, just [look it up](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample). Python has great documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it can help you,

```
class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
            random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
```

is equivalent to

```
class_names = []
for w in random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%")):
    class_names.append(w.capitalize())
```

The .count() will return the number of occurence of "%%%" in the snippet string, so the random.sample will select a subset of N elements from the WORDS list where N is the element of "%%%" in the snippet string.

Answer (score 1):

`w.capitalize()` is like `.uppercase()`, but it only captilizes the first character.